# conversion from Color To int for SETCHARFORMAT meaaage

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to convert an `object Color`, to `Int`, to put him in `crTextColor` member, so I used the method `myColor.ToArgb()`, but the color changes, and displays a different color.

Why is this happening?

this is the code:

```
      CHARFORMAT2 fmt = new CHARFORMAT2();
      fmt.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(fmt);
      // check if the text contains CFE_AUTOCOLOR effect
      SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, Handle), EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref fmt);
      if ((fmt.dwEffects & CFE_AUTOCOLOR) == CFE_AUTOCOLOR)
      {
          fmt.dwEffects -= CFE_AUTOCOLOR;
      }
      fmt.dwMask = CFM_COLOR;
      Color c = Color.Red;
      fmt.crTextColor =  c.ToArgb();
      SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, Handle), EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref fmt);
```

Comment: Does Char format 2 use argb or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine. Are you doing something different?

```
int crTextColor;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    crTextColor = BackColor.ToArgb();//To number
    Text = crTextColor.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackColor = Color.FromArgb(crTextColor);//From number
}
```

EDIT: (After seeing your edit)

OK. So you got me there, I don't really know this stuff. But:

If you go to MSDN's page on `CHARFORMAT2` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and search in it for `crTextColor`you'll find (as the fifth case) the explanation to it. It says its type is: COLORREF . If you'll click on that link - it says that it is `RGB`. Clicking on the `RGB` link there goes to here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx which says:

```
 C++

COLORREF RGB(
  BYTE byRed,
  BYTE byGreen,
  BYTE byBlue
);
```

On the other hand - if you go here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb.aspx you see (in "remarks") that `Color.ToArgb`is `ARGB` :

> "The most significant byte (MSB), represented by AA, is the alpha
>   component value."

So *perhaps* that's the problem. But, again, **I don't really know this stuff!** I just did some searching.

Comment: but this code not work: CHARFORMAT2 fmt = new CHARFORMAT2();
        fmt.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(fmt);
        // check if the text contains CFE_AUTOCOLOR effect
        SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, Handle), EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref fmt);
                if ((fmt.dwEffects & CFE_AUTOCOLOR) == CFE_AUTOCOLOR)
        {
            fmt.dwEffects -= CFE_AUTOCOLOR;
        }
        fmt.dwMask = CFM_COLOR;
        Color c = Color.Red;
        fmt.crTextColor =  c.ToArgb();
        SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, Handle), SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref fmt);

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

```
int myColorVal = myColor.ToArgb();
someobject.crTextColor = Color.FromArgb( myColorVal );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using binary and shift operators.

```
Int32 key = color.R << 16 | color.G << 8 | color.B;
```